# What C standard says about bitwise XOR of two signed integers?

Tags: c, xor, signed

Which ANSI C standard says something about bit wise XOR of two *signed* integers? I tried to read the standard, but it is vast.

XOR of two signed integers is valid as per C standard? What will happen to the sign bit of the result?

Comment: The "duplicate" doesn't address ^ in particular nor does it cite the standard anywhere. Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operations operate on *bits*, that is, on the actual 1's and 0's of the data. Therefore, sign is irrelevant; the result of the operation is what you'd get from writing out the series of 1's and 0's that represents each integer and then XORing each corresponding pair of bits. (Even type information is irrelevant, as long as the operands are integers of some sort, as opposed to doubles, pointers, etc.)

Comment: maybe you can quote `6.5.11 of ISO/IEC 9899 : TC3`

Comment: I've...never actually read the standard. Haven't done enough C programming for that to be worth my time.

Comment: its maked duplicate anyways..:)